# How can I update a TextField's text after tapping on "Done" on a TimePicker in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a TextField and when I tap on this TextField a TimePicker is shown.
I set the time and when I tap on "Done" the TextField's text isn't updated!

I'm using setState(), but I suppose I'm using it wrong...

This is driving me crazy, please help me!

Thanks in advance.

```
Container
(
   height: resLayout.getScreenHeightPercentage(context, 10),
   width: resLayout.getScreenWidthPercentage(context, 35),
   padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 0.0),
   child: TextField
   (
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'hh : mm', contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0), border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(25.0))), filled: false),
      style: TextStyle
      (
         fontSize: 24
      ),
      controller: datacontroller,
      readOnly: true,
      onTap: ()
      {
         DatePicker.showTimePicker
         (
            context, showTitleActions: true,
            onConfirm: (time)
            {
               datacontroller.text = DateFormat("kk:mm").format(time);
               setState(() {});
            },
            currentTime: DateTime.now(),
            locale: LocaleType.it
         );
      },
   ),
)
```

Comment: are you getting any error? If not provide full runnable code, because, from the looks of it, there is nothing wrong with the code, it works when I use the same code in my app and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: @dlohani Nope, I don't get any error, the VS Code debug console is clear too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datacontroller.text = DateFormat("kk:mm").format(time);
           setState(() {});
```

You need to put any state you want to update inside the braces of setState. So it would become

```
setState(() {
     datacontroller.text = DateFormat("kk:mm").format(time);
});
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

//Class State here
var textInput = TextEditingController();

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'hh : mm',
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(25.0))),
            filled: false),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        controller: textInput,
        readOnly: true,
        onTap: () {
          DatePicker.showTimePicker(context, showTitleActions: true,
              onConfirm: (time) {
            setState(() {
              textInput.text = DateFormat("kk:mm").format(time);
            });
          }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.it);
        },
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Full project repo if you want it.
https://github.com/kenthinson/datestateexample

Comment: It doesn't work! `setState(() { datacontroller.text = DateFormat("kk:mm").format(time); });`

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong too. I’m not at the computer now. But you always need to put inside set state so that was at least half the problem. I’ll look later when I can

Comment: Also no need to be rude using “!” You are getting free help after all.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you using "!" is rude, but it was for the problem, to for you.....I appreciate a lot your help and I am sorry if you saw my exclamation as rudeness.

Comment: I have tested and verified the code. Added example. and created a repo for you with the full project files.

Comment: Your code is same as mine. I can't understand what I did wrong also because your code runs perfectly after compiling and deploying it on my device. How can I send you my `code.dart`? Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to check your pubspec.yamal is the same for the package. That comes to my head first.

Comment: Let me say another thing....when I compile my code this warning is shown on VS Code Debug Console: `Launching lib/main.dart on HUAWEI NMO L31 in debug mode...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true`. Is it a problem for the TimePicker?

Comment: As I've answered the original question can you please mark it so. I'm not sure why your project is not working correctly but it's not a code problem it's a project problem. You can always open another question about the debug console.

Comment: I solved the problem replacing `intl: ^0.16.0` with `intl: ^0.15.8` in my `pubspec.yaml`. Thank you @kent

Comment: There's nothing magical about the body of code passed to setState.  It's mostly just documentation about *why* you are updating your state, but you can also lift that body to just before the setState.  The style guide suggests that an empty body for setState is a code smell.

Comment: Not sure what you a referring to in the docs Randal. I have had first hand experience when accidentally putting a state change above setstate as you say should work and it would not update until moved inside. ￼

From the docs:
Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the change in a function that you pass to setState:

The provided callback is immediately called synchronously. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html